# iTextSharp and embedded fonts

Tags: c#, itext

I have an existing PDF (source PDF) with some text using font ARIAL. I need to convert source PDF to PDF/A-1b. For this, I just create a new PDF/a-1b, set necessary xmp and copy page from the standard PDF (using `getImportedPage` in a loop). But I don't know how to "force" to embbed the font for the existing text that comes with my source PDF.

Is it possible to reference font (and insert it in PDF) for existing text?

Comment: If a font isn't embedded, you need to find the font file for every font that is used and then embed the font "post facto" as is done in this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=288 For the C# version of this example, see http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter16/EmbedFontPostFacto.cs

Comment: Thanks, it work. My PDF have both Arial and Arial,Bold but I believe that it's the same font file (Arial.ttf). May I inject twice the font for each font reference ?

Comment: Arial needs arial.ttf; Arial bold needs arialbd.ttf. Those are two *different fonts* belonging to the *same family*.